Merging multiple similar dataframes in r
There has got to be an easier way to merge 35 similar dataframes than full joining 35 times!
counties_9022<-full_join(cnty90, cnty91) %>% 
  full_join(cnty92) %>% 
  full_join(cnty93) %>% 
  full_join(cnty94)

I wrote ~30 more lines of code to merge them all. what's an easier way? would I use a for loop?
Files - basically merging all the County High-Level files on this page https://www.bls.gov/cew/downloadable-data-files.htm

Put your data in a list, maybe something like cnty_data = mget(ls(pattern = "cnty[0-9]+")) if they all follow that naming pattern, then result = Reduce(full_join, cnty_data)

Before you do this, do make sure full_join is what you want. If you just need to stack them on top of each other, use dplyr::bind_rows(cnty_data). If you just need to stack them next to each other, use dplyr::bind_cols(cnty_data).

thank you! yeah i just needed to stack them on top of each other. so would it be cnty_data = mget(ls(pattern = "cnty[0-9]+")) and then dplyr::bind_cols(cnty_data) ?

No, bind_rows(cnty_data)
